# Is it not recommended to accept an answer quickly, because it might not encourage users to write more answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

A moderator [told me to not accept an answer too soon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/49979/is-right-concentration-the-same-thing-as-jhana?noredirect=1#comment80548_49979) because it hinders users from writing more answers. But the accepted answer fits my needs, AND it even looks like a Canonical Answer to me.

Is that a generally accepted advice?

If we should not accept answers too soon, why isn't the accept button blocked for a few hours/days?

Comment: The mod was just trying to help you get the best response you could, based on how answerers act.

Comment: "the accepted answer fits my needs" - great, but there's always a chance to get a better answer. That's the idea behind this practice.

Comment: @philipxy he said "if you can please not ..." - I'm not a native English speaker, so maybe I misunderstood his tone, but it sounded to me as if this was not just "trying to help me get the best response", but as if he had a specific preference. But anyway.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry yes, I agree this is a duplicate. Can I vote to close as duplicate? Don't want to delete, but close as duplicate.

Comment: Yes you can, after you vote to close your question as duplicate you will get a banner letting you to insta-close it as well. If you get into trouble with this let me know and I'll use my hammer.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry sorry, don't see a close button. Maybe not enough rep. I flagged it as a duplicate.

Comment: All good, I closed it. Also, a side note: the user who posted the answer can't reply to your comment there as they're suspended.

Comment: Anyway, I've started a chat, you should get invitation. If you want feel free to join. :-) (No worry just curious about some things)

Comment: The best response would come from you not doing something. So that's what they said. And best isn't just for you but for the site. Besides all that, you seem to be making a lot of very little. Comments are a very low bandwidth channel.